# (Firefox, Cometbird, Explorer) Hover not working when the element is made from javascript/jquery

Tags: css, hover

Hover not working. I tested this to Firefox 19.0, Cometbird 11.0, Explorer 9.

the only browser I tested to work is Chrome 25.

What this code do?

First, when mouse hover to element #wrap_req, it will call a function that tells to add html content inside #wrap_req.

```
<span id='cancelReq' ></span>
```

And then when the mouse hover to element #cancelReq, the background of that element must change.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function mOver(x)
    {   
        var txt = 'cond1';      //let's say it this way to satisfies the IF

        if(txt == 'cond1')          
        {
            var txt2 = "<span id='cancelReq' ></span>";
            $('#wrap_req').html(txt2);
            $('#cancelReq').css('display', x);  

        }   
    }   
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
    #wrap_req{width:193px; margin:0 auto; border:1px solid red;}
    #cancelReq{display:none; background-image:url(../images/cancel.png); }  
    #cancelReq:hover{background-image:url(../images/cancel2.png);}  
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id='wrap_req' onmouseover=\"mOver('block')\" onmouseout=\"mOver('none')\" >

</div>
```

I've tried to add the code below to the function mOver(), inside the IF Statement.

If, I add alert(), it works fine. The background image changes.

But I need not to use that alert();

```
$('#cancelReq').hover(                          
    function
    {           
        //alert('entered Friends');
        $('#cancelReq').css('background', '#eeeeee');
    }
);
```

Comment: where is the `unFriend` element? Can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry I made a wrong copy/paste. the unFriend must be "cancelReq". I updated my question. thanks

Comment: are you testing it in Firefox if yes version

Comment: @ArunPJohny I tested it at Firefox 19.0

Comment: I think firefox 19 has a some bug, I saw another question with same case today

Comment: which jquery version you are using?

Comment: @ssilas777 1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've tested this to chrome. works fine. Now I know that the error is on Firefox. How can I resolve this :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I suggest that you bind your events using either the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) method or jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/). It's easier and cleaner than writing inline JavaScript.

I think your problem is the fact that `#cancelReq` is a dynamically created DOM element and you bind the [.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event *before* it's even created. You can either use jQuery's [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method or bind the event when the DOM element is created.

I understand that you want to toggle the visibility and the color of the background of the `span` element? If it's the case, you can manage it by using CSS *exclusively*, which is better for performance and maintainability of your code.